# Getting 404 on my app

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE application I'm developing. I've been away for about two weeks and have not used the app. Today I get a 404, not found. How could my app disappear? I can still log in as administrator and the app seems to be set up correctly but even using the links from admin I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

A GAE app doesn't disappear with a 404 error...
You should have another setup issue.

Have a look to the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating?)

Comment: You were right. Pilot error. I need to take shorter vacations. Thanks for taking the time to respond.